# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value "i" is not a reference value [proguard.evaluation.value.UnknownIntegerValue]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I have using "com.guardsquare:proguard-gradle:7.0.0" but I cannot build app, it always show Exception with Kotlin class.
Please help to find any causing, thank you so much.

[image]